# IntelliJ can't find jdk documentation even though when I visit the URL it works

Tags: java, oracle, intellij-idea, javadoc

When I try to view javadocs in Intellij 13 or 14, it doesn't work. I see this error message:

> Following external urls were checked:
>   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()
>   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--
>   The documentation for this element is not found. Please add all the
>   needed paths to API docs in Project Settings.

Yet, if you visit those URLs, the javadoc is right there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136556) which will be fixed in IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

Still(?) broken in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.5
Build #IU-162.2228.15, built on October 14, 2016

Claims to be fixed in the Early-Access 2016.3 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-158690

Comment: Please don't add _Me too!_ as answers. It doesn't actually provide an answer to the question and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. If you have a different but related question, then [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) it (reference this one if it will help provide context). If you're interested in this specific question, you can [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) it or leave a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).